# Make panel bigger in width javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a panel that's to small i width. I try to expand it but then the app crashes. Here's my code:

```
var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
  .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0,3]))
  .build();

  var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
  .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]))
  .build();

  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data)
  .bind([filterSalesTotal, filterName, filterSalesType], [tableChart, pieChart])
  .build();


  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var filterPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var chartPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  filterPanel.add(filterName).add(filterSalesType).add(filterSalesTotal).setSpacing(12);
  chartPanel.add(pieChart).add(tableChart).setSpacing(12);

  dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(filterPanel).add(tableChart).add(chartPanel));
  app.add(dashboard);
  return app;


}
```

I tried to enter this but then the app crashes:

```
dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel.setWidth(400).add(filterPanel).add(tableChart).add(chartPanel));
  app.add(dashboard);
  return app;
```

I get the following error:

TypeError: Can not find function setWidth in object function createvVerticalPanel() {/ ** /}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you simply forgot a pair of parenthesis ... and also the argument should be a string as shown in the autocomplete (control+space while typing).

[image]

```
  dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel().setWidth('400').add(filterPanel).add(tableChart).add(chartPanel));
  app.add(dashboard);
  return app;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now the App dosen't creash anymore, i should have seen that my self :P...

However the panel isn't changing anything as you can see in my picture:

http://i.imgur.com/J3mLDQX.png

I would like it to be bigger =)

Comment: if I understand well, you should use .setDimensions(width, height) on the tableChart widget directly.